# How to have Git highlight forked changes?

Tags: git, version-control

I am working on a project which uses a slightly modified version of another repository. Occasionally changes are made to the forked repository which require my modifications to be reconsidered.

Is there an easy way to highlight new changes which surround or overwrite the changes which I have made in my customised version? i.e. without having to sift through every change in the other repository.

Perhaps there is a recommended workflow for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, there is a way. The syntax is:

```
 https://github.com/VonC/ForkedRepoName/compare/forkedAuthor:branch...yourBranch
```

For instance, I forked https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js and want to compare my branch `attributes` to his branch `dev`:

https://github.com/VonC/reveal.js/compare/hakimel:dev...attributes

(which doesn't show anything since my branch was merged into his branch)

Or:

https://github.com/VonC/reveal.js/compare/hakimel:master...embed

Which shows that I didn't update embed branch in a while.